# graphviz - multiple links per label

Tags: svg, graphviz

I was looking for a away to add more than one link to a label for svg export, but I can't have more than one edge.

Right now I have something like this:

```
Node1 -> Node2 [ href="some.resource.xyz", label="Resource\nAdditionalInfo" ]
```

What I need though is to have something like this:

```
Node1 -> Node2 [
  label="Resource\n              # href to "some.resource.xyz"
         Additional Information" # href to some.additional.info
]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [HTML label](https://graphviz.gitlab.io/_pages/doc/info/shapes.html#html) and define a table with two cell with different values for HREF attribute

Example:

```
digraph {
    A->B
    B[label=<<table>
    <tr><td href="http://google.com">Google</td></tr>
    <tr><td href="http://bing.com">Bing</td></tr>
    </table>>]
}
```